# F# Get Members of Module

Tags: reflection, module, f#, member

Given

```
type Unit = {
            Name : string
            Abbreviation : string
            Value : float
        }

module Lets =
    let meter = { Name = "meter"; Abbreviation = "m"; Value = 1.0 }
    let millimeter = { Name = "millimeter"; Abbreviation = "mm"; Value = 1e-3 }
```

How can I create a function with this signature?

```
let units () : Units[] = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# Modules are just static classes when compiled.

Using reflection you should be able to grab these values with something like this:

```
module Lets =
    type Dummy = | Dummy
    let meter = { Name = "meter"; Abbreviation = "m"; Value = 1.0 }
    let millimeter = { Name = "millimeter"; Abbreviation = "mm"; Value = 1e-3 }


let t = typeof<Lets.Dummy>.DeclaringType
t.GetProperties() |> Array.map(fun p -> p.GetValue(null, null) :?> Unit)
```

It's tricky to get the type of the module, but that trick will do it for you.

EDIT:

Updated to cast directly to `Unit`.
The cast as shown is unsafe, and will throw if `GetValue` does not return a `Unit` type.

Additionally `unit` is a type in F#, it might be clearer to use a different name.

Comment: Very good. I edited my answer to include the definition of the `Unit` type and that I want to return `Units[]` instead of `obj[]`.

Comment: In that case you'd have to hard cast to a `Units`, I'll update my answer accordingly